# mysql - update a field in 1 table where another field in that table = a field in another table

Tags: mysql

Need help with a mysql query. I have 2 tables - table1 and table2. I am trying to update a field in table1 which is not included in table2 - named Status. And I want to update that field with the value of 'A'. table1 and table2 DO have a field in common - named Member_ID. Here is my query that is giving me errors:

```
UPDATE table1 SET Status='A' WHERE Member_ID=table2.Member_ID;
```

Is there some type of join that is needed? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.
cdr6800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with exists

```
UPDATE table1 s
SET s.status = 'A'
WHERE EXISTS(select 1 from table2 t
             WHERE t.member_id = s.member_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `JOIN` `table1` to `table2` like this:

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.Member_ID = t2.Member_ID
SET t1.Status='A'
```

This will update all `table1` records having a `Member_ID` value that also exists in `table2`.

Comment: Thank you very much Giorgos. Worked great! Have a nice day.

Comment: @cdr6800 Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.